# Iterating over particular attributes of instances of objects in python

Tags: python, oop

I'm a novice programmer, so please pardon me for not using Python-specific vocabulary.

Suppose I define a class **CarSpecs** with attributes *CarReg*, *Make*, *Model* and *Color*, create several instances of this class (call them records) and one by one append them to a text file named *SuperCars*. What I want my program to do is to read the whole file and return the number of cars which are Red (i.e. by looking up the attribute *Color* of each instance).

Here's what I've done so far:

Defined a class:

```
class Carspecs(object):  
    def __init__(self, carreg, make, model, color):    
        self.CarReg = carreg   
        self.Make = make  
        self.Model = model   
        self.Color = color
```

Then I created several instances and defined a function to add the instances(or you can say ''records'') to **SuperCars**:

```
def addCar(CarRecord):  
   import pickle  
       CarFile = open('Supercars', 'ab')  
       pickle.dump(CarRecord, CarFile)  
       CarFile.close()
```

What do I do next to output the number of Red cars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to open that file again, read all of the records and then see which cars `Color` attribute equals red. Because you're saving each instance in the pickle you will have to do something like the following:

```
>>> with open('Supercars', 'rb') as f:
...    data = []
...    while True:
...        try:
...            data.append(pickle.load(f))
...        except EOFError:
...            break
...
>>>
>>> print(x for x in data if x.Color == 'red')
```

I suggest you store the data in a list and pickle that list, this way you don't have to use that hacky loop the get *all* items. Storing such a list is easy. Assume you've created a list of `CarSpec`-objects and stored them in a list `records`:

```
>>> with open('Supercars', 'wb') as f:
...    pickle.dump(records, f)
...
>>>
```

and then reading it is as simple as:

```
>>> with open('Supercars', 'rb') as f:
...     data = pickle.load(f)
...
>>>
```

And you can even filter it easily:

```
>>> with open('Supercars', 'rb') as f:
...     data = [x for x in pickle.load(f) if x.Color == 'Red']
...
>>>
```

If you want to display before you're storing them in the pickle you can just iterate over the `records`-list and print cars with a red color.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an elaborate reply!